# Filter cqwp by items updated this year

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, cqwp

I want to show only the items whose "Modified" field is in this year.

The filter fields allow me to insert - or Today, or specific date, or a constant number of days before\after today, but the number of days from the beginning of this year changes every day...

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that no one answered the question,

So I'll write what I did in the end, maybe it will help someone.

I created a calculated column that returns the value "X" if the value of the field `Modified` is in this year (in a calculated column formula I could do the checking I wanted) and the value "Y" if not,

And in the CQWP - I filter by this column.